# PHP speed up for-loop for rankings

Tags: php, laravel

we are currently working on a tournament platform. This platform does generate rankings completely dynamic, so we have different points, different amount of participants etc. everytime.

A tournament can have multiple rounds. For each round an admin can set the ranking for a participant. And this is where the problem lies. My current code:

```html
<select name="round_{{ $i }}_placements[{{ $participant->id }}]" class="form-control scoreboard-placement">
 @for($x=0;$x<$tournament->checkedin()->count()+1;$x++)
  <option value="{{ $x }}" @if($participant->getRanking($i)->ranking_value == $x) selected="selected" @endif>{{ $x }}</option>
 @endfor
</select>
```

But I do have a huge problem with loading times now:

In my last case I had 67 participants. For each participant he went through and added all those 67 select options. But it also checked 67 times the ranking, which should obviously not happen. This increases the loading time of our backend to almost 30 seconds, which is huge. When I removed them, it went back to 2.

So what I want instead is: Create all of the options once and automatically change the selected box. Do you guys know how I can achieve this? Switching to JS for changing would be no problem as well.

Comment: You could try installing xDebug and profiling your application. Look at where the time is spent and that will help you to improve speed.

Comment: I have checked where I have to improve speed, and this is at this specific part. I have the problem that I do multiple thousand requests (67x67) for those rankings, while I'd only need 67.

Comment: I rolled back the answer, as this is the base question. You should not uypdate it accoring to answers, because the answers would not make sense. This way, someone can see a before/after and learn from it

Answer (score 7):

You should do `$trnmntCheckedinCount = $tournament->checkedin()->count()` and use that in the loop. Now you call these methods once per entry (so 67 times). My suggestion does it once, it should matter some.

You check if the persons ranking is `$x` per user, per option (so 10 options with 67 participants means 670 checks). You should check the users rank before the options `for`, and just check said variable. This should matter a lot :)

---

My laravel is barely existent, but something like this:

```
@php
// Place this out of the loop which loops through your users
$tournementCount = $tournament->checkedin()->count();
@endphp

<select name="round_{{ $i }}_placements[{{ $participant->id }}]" class="form-control scoreboard-placement">
    @php
        $participantRanking = $participant->getRanking($i)->ranking_value;
    @endphp

    @for($x=0; $x<$tournementCount+1; $x++)
        <option value="{{ $x }}" @if( $participantRanking == $x ) selected @endif>{{ $x }}</option>
    @endfor
</select>
```

Comment: Hey Martijn! This has helped. It reduced the load by almost 65%. I have edited it in the post. However, the ranking issue which creates about 4k requests (and even more if more participants) still exists.

Comment: After you edited it, it was clear. Big thanks. Sometimes the easiest things are out of your head if you sit 2 hours in front of it. That was my issue! Thank you really much, saved a lot of time.

Comment: Merci @Classified